# Hide pages if there isn't enough entries

Tags: xpages

I have created a repeat control that list some documents.
I would like to have a pages that shows only if the number of entries
is more than max number of entries specified in the repeat control.

Is it possible to find out how many entries is currently displayed in the repeat control?
Or what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some SSJS that can help:

```
var r:com.ibm.xsp.component.UIRepeat = getComponent("repeat1"); 
var count = r.getRowCount() // returns all entries
var pos = r.getFirst(); // returns current position of first entry
var rows = r.getRows(); // get rows of repeat controls

var curPage = pos / rows + 1;
var pagesTotal = ( count - (count % rows)) / rows + 1;
```

**EDIT:**

To compute the number of the currently displayed entries, you can do the following:

```
if( curPage == pagesTotal ){
   return (count % rows)
}else{
   return rows;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this help? http://www.mydominolab.com/2010/10/repeat-control-better-navigation.html

I think you can simply compare `getRowCount() > getRows()`